# How do I make a C++ Dll for a C# Forms that calls a DirectX function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, dll, directx

I wanna make a DirectX application that uses C# Forms for window handling because that's what I'm most familiar with. I made a C++ Dll project and added these dependencies to get DirectX under Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies.

```
d3d11.lib
dxgi.lib
dxguid.lib
uuid.lib
kernel32.lib
user32.lib
comdlg32.lib
advapi32.lib
shell32.lib
ole32.lib
oleaut32.lib
```

And I set the SubSystem under System to Windows. And set the output folder to the bin folder of the C# Forms project so I don't have to copy paste every time I build the C++ project. I then add two files, A header and a cpp file.

### TestExport.h

```
#pragma once

#include "pch.h"

#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#include <d3d11_1.h>
#include <directxcolors.h>
#include <wrl/client.h>

using namespace DirectX;

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) void __cdecl Test();
}
```

### TestExport.cpp

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "TestExport.h"

void Test()
{
    ID3DBlob *pBlob;
    D3D10CreateBlob(12, &pBlob);
    delete pBlob;
}
```

I know that the function in TestExport.cpp currently doesn't do anything but it will be replaced with some real method when the problem gets fixed.
The problem is that I get a `LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _D3D10CreateBlob@8` error as soon as I call the `D3D10CreateBlob` method. I don't have that much knowledge about Dll's and I have no clue what to search to find a awnser or a lead

Comment: I did notice that when I change to build target from x86 to x64 the error changes from _D3D10CreateBlob@8 to simply D3D10CreateBlob and the error changes to LNK2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for helping me in finding or explain my problem :)

To link to DirectX i added the include path in *Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories*. visual studio thankfully has a macro for the include folder called *$(WindowsSDK_IncludePath)*.

Then I went to *Configuration Properties -> Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories* and set the x64 platform to *$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x64)* and the x86 to *$(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86)*.

I also changed the *Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies* to include

```
dxgi.lib
d3d11.lib
d3d12.lib
d3d10.lib
d3dcompiler.lib
```

which I think is the acctuall problem I had. That I didn't include `d3d10.lib` * facepalms *